# How to send and email if a task doesn't run by a certain time of day in Airflow

Tags: email, airflow

I am setting up a DAG which initiates with a sensor. The sensor checks to see if some files have been loaded that morning. If the files haven't loaded by 12pm that day, I want to schedule an email instead. What is the best way to approach this and can you create a time dependent ifelse logic?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need to implement SLA: https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/concepts.html#slas

> Service Level Agreements, or time by which a task or DAG should have
> succeeded, can be set at a task level as a timedelta. If one or many
> instances have not succeeded by that time, an alert email is sent
> detailing the list of tasks that missed their SLA. The event is also
> recorded in the database and made available in the web UI under
> Browse->SLA Misses where events can be analyzed and documented.
>
> SLAs can be configured for scheduled tasks by using the sla parameter.
> In addition to sending alerts to the addresses specified in a task’s
> email parameter, the sla_miss_callback specifies an additional
> Callable object to be invoked when the SLA is not met.

A complete Airflow SLA tutorial: https://blog.clairvoyantsoft.com/airflow-service-level-agreement-sla-2f3c91cd84cc